# Proof by induction. Two different ways. Which one is valid?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification, induction

**Ex. 1**

Let's say we want to prove that $n^2 > 2n, \qquad \forall n \geq 3 \in \mathbb{N}$. So first, we would check our base case $n = 3$. Obviously we have $3^2 > 2\cdot 3 = 9 > 6$.

Now our inductive step. We have $\ k^2 > 2k\ $. We add $\ 2k+1 \ $ on both sides, yielding $\ k^2 + 2k + 1 > 2k + 2k + 1$. Because we have $2k > 1$, we can add a $1$ on the right side of the inequation. We have $k^2 + 2k + 1 > 4k + 2 = (k+1)^2 > 2(k+1)$ $\blacksquare$

**Ex. 2**

Now if we expand $(n+1)^2 > 2(n+1)$ we have $n^2 + 2n + 1 > 2n + 2$. Since we assume $n^2 > 2n$ to be true, could we simply subtract this on both sides? This would leave us with $2n + 1 > 2$, which is trivially true for any $n \geq 2$. Is this valid, and is this enough to prove the original statement?

Comment: I would take the second one over the first one any day.

Comment: The second method is hard to follow.  Specifically:  you start by assuming what you want to conclude.  Then you manipulate it, finally winding up with something true...and then you stop.  Implicitly, I guess, you are suggesting that each of the manipulations was reversible, so that you could have started with true things and obtained the desired conclusion.  But with inequalities involved, reversing the steps should be made explicit.   I suggest rewriting the argument, starting with a clear statement of what assumptions on $n$ you are making.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! I should be friendly to new visitors, so please excuse the "grumpy old man" attitude, that's just me. In fact, your MathJax is great! But you should write your formulas more carefully, so people will be more inclined to answer. Notably $\forall n\geq3\in\Bbb N$ (1) does not parse, and (2) like other operators introducing variables ($\exists,\sum,\int,\lim$) the operator $\forall$ should come _in front_ of the scope of the variable it introduces, not at the back (it seems that half the world cannot understand this simple rule).

Comment: The second one is sometimes referred to "reverse induction," and can be seen as a bad thing. That is, you start noting you want to prove the $n+1$ case, form a series of equivalencies, and end up with something true. This is a confusing way of presenting the logic-- it's generally better to start with something true or your hypothesis, and work *up* to the $n+1$ case, rather than backwards.

Comment: More to the point, just adding $1$ to the smaller side of an inequality is not a good plan, whatever other inequality you invoke to justify it, so your Ex. 1 does not seem to work. Also $4k+2=(k+1)^2$ occurs in your text; this is probably not what you wanted to say (and in any case not true).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Ex. 1**

- You wrote "$n^2 > 2n, \qquad \forall n \geq 3 \in \mathbb{N}$". This is problematic for two reasons: if you use the symbol $\forall$ rather than the words "for all", then this symbol must be placed *before* the formula in question; also, $\forall n\ge3\in\Bbb{N}$ reads as "for all $n$ greater than $3$, which is a natural number". You want to say that $n$ is a natural number, not $3$, and so should rearrange things. Both of the following are correct (though I personally prefer the second):
  \begin{align}
  \require{cancel}
  &\forall n(n\in\Bbb{N} \text{ and }n\ge3\implies n^2>2n) \\
  &\forall n\in\Bbb{N}(n\ge3 \implies n^2>2n) \, .
  \end{align}
  Even better is to use words: "every natural number greater than or equal to $3$ satisfies $n^2>3n$".
- For the base case, presumably you meant to write $3^2=9>2 \cdot 3=6$. What you have written is incorrect. Depending on how much detail your instructors demand, you could also simply say "the statement is obviously true for the base case".
- Starting with $k^2>2k$, you add $2k+1$ to both sides of the inequality to get $k^2+2k+1>2k+2k+1$, which is fine. However, the justification you gave for why you can $1$ to the RHS does not make sense to me. In any case, the following argument is simpler. You want to show that
  $$
  k^2>2k \implies (k+1)^2>2(k+1) \, ,
  $$
  so offer the following argument:
  $$
  k^2+2k+1=(k+1)^2>4k+1>2(k+1) \, .
  $$
  The final inequality is true because $4k+1>2(k+1) \iff k>-\frac{1}{2}$.

**Ex. 2**

- Your proof is written backwards: rather than showing $k^2>2k \implies (k+1)^2>2(k+1)$, you try to show $(k+1)^2>2(k+1) \implies k^2>2k$. That's not the same thing: note that $x=5 \implies x^2=25$, but $x^2=25{\cancel\implies} x=5$. Sometimes writing proofs backwards is acceptable because all of the steps are reversible. For instance, to prove that for all real numbers $x$ and $y$, $\sqrt{xy}<\frac{x+y}{2}$, we can do the following:
  \begin{align}
  \sqrt{xy} < \frac{x+y}{2} &\iff 4xy < (x+y)^2 \\[4pt]
  &\iff x^2-2xy+y^2 > 0 \\[4pt]
  &\iff (x-y)^2>0
  \end{align}
  Since $\sqrt{xy}<\frac{x+y}{2} \iff (x-y)^2>0$, we can conclude that $(x-y)^2>0 \implies \sqrt{xy} < \frac{x+y}{2}$. Moreover, since the LHS of this implication is true for all real $x$ and $y$. However, when trying to prove that $A \implies B$, this method doesn't work if it is not the case that $B \implies A$. So exercise caution with this method.
- To write a reverse proof by induction, you have to show that $P(k+1) \iff P(k)$. If you start by assuming that $P(k+1)$, you cannot assume that $P(k)$ is true as you did. So your method is not valid.

Answer (score 1):

**Ex. 1:** After getting $x^2+2k+1>2k+2k+1$, you *cannot* simply add $1$ to the right side (unless you add it to the left side too). Besides, $4k+2\ne2(k+1)$. But, since $2k+1$, $2k+2k+1>2k+2=2(k+1)$.

**Ex. 2:** I don't know why you are assuming that $n^2>2n$, but if you are… so what? You have $4>3$ and $5>1$, but you don't have $4-3>3-1$.

Answer (score 1):

In your first proof, you should not write things like

> $3^2>2\cdot 3=9>6$

because $2\cdot 3\neq 9$. You probably mean $3^2>2\cdot 3\Leftrightarrow 9>6$, showing that the inequalities are equivalent. There is also a small mistake at the end; you cannot just add $1$ to the right side, but you can replace the summand $2k$ by $1$ making the sum smaller, and thus getting $$(k+1)^2=k^2+2k+1>2k+2k+1>2k+1+1=2(k+1)$$

$\ $

Your second proof is kind of correct, but badly written. You should never start with the statement you want to prove and transform it to something that is true, since a wrong statement can imply a true one as well. You could basically write your prove backwards: Since $2n+1>2$, we get $\ldots$

Alternatively, another save way is to start at one side and manipulate it until you are done. For example you could write $$(n+1)^2=n^2+2n+1\overset{\substack{\text{Inductive}\\\text{hypothesis}}}>2n+2n+1\overset{2n+1>2}>2n+2=2(n+1)$$ which basically mimics your proof, but is written in a neater way.